# How do a delete rows starting with "-" plus 3 rows after

Tags: python, parsing

I am I have test data that looks like this. It comprises on 1 column .CSV consiting of

```
"----------"

PAGE1

PARAGRAPH

EXAMPLE

example1

example2

example3

example4

example5

"----------"

PAGE2

PARAGRAPH

EXAMPLE

example1

example2

example3

example4

example5
```

The aim is to remove the 4 rows containing the

```
"------"

PAGE

PARAGRAPH

EXAMPLE
```

so that i can output a just a list of examples

```
import csv
input = open('Test_Parse.csv', 'rb')
output = open('first_edit.csv', 'wb')
writer = csv.writer(output)
for row in csv.reader ('Test_Parse.csv'):
if not row.startswith ("------"):
    writer.writerow(row)
input.close()
output.close()
```

This is an attempt to remove the row with the `"------"` but struggling?

Any help or pointing in right direction would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Please mark my answer as correct if it worked for you.

Answer (score 2):

Treating `fileobject` as iterator:

```
import csv

with open('Test_Parse.csv', 'r') as inp, open('first_edit.csv', 'w', newline='') as out:
    writer = csv.writer(out)
    for l in inp:
        if l.startswith('"------'):
            next(inp)  # extract the next line from the file to skip
            next(inp)
            next(inp)
        else:
            writer.writerow((l.strip(),))
```

---

The final `first_edit.csv` contents:

```
example1
example2
example3
example4
example5
example1
example2
example3
example4
example5
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a simple idea of a line counter.

- At the beginning, initialize counter to 0.
- For every line you read:

  - If the line is "------", set the counter to zero.
  - Increase the counter by 1
  - If the counter is 5 or more, print the line.

Answer (score 0):

Just convert your rows to an iter and call next skipping the rows you dont want. See:

```
import csv
input = open('Test_Parse.csv', 'rb')
output = open('first_edit.csv', 'wb')
writer = csv.writer(output)
rows = iter(csv.reader ('Test_Parse.csv'))
for row in rows:
    if row.startswith ("------"):
        next(rows)
        next(rows)
        next(rows)    
    else:
        writer.writerow(row)
input.close()
output.close()
```

If I were you I would do some reading on iter() and next()

see for example: https://www.programiz.com/python-programming/iterator

Notice that RomanPerekhrest answer using with() also makes sense as you do not need to call .close() on input and output.